# how to get child element using inline javascript in htmltag

Tags: javascript

Here is the code

```
<a href="http://example.com/example-2pp.html" onmouseover="alert(this.children[1].src)">
    <span class="product-image-container product-image-container-1198" style="width: 388px;">
        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 125%;">
            <img class="product-image-photo" src="http://example.com/media/catalog/product/l/i/example_d17163a-a00_t-shirt_bra_white-min.jpg?width=388&amp;height=485&amp;store=example_en&amp;image-type=small_image">
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I want to get the img src using this line of script

```
onmouseover="alert(this.children[1].src)">
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: With that particular line? No. `this.children[1]` doesn't exist (the `a` only has one child and that selects the second). And the `img` is a great-grandchild (not a child) of the `a`. You can't completely ignore layers of your DOM.

Comment: To start with you should not use inline JS attributes `on*`, just like you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes (*edit:* you do!). JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag of file. Use `addEventListener()` instead. And use `console.log()` to inspect your stuff.

Comment: Also, use rather the `"mouseenter"` event name - not the mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [Element.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- Use the `"mouseenter"` Event name
- PS: Avoid using inline `on*` or `style` attributes. JS and CSS should be in their respective tags or files!

```html
<a href="http://example.com/example-2pp.html" onmouseenter="alert(this.querySelector('img')?.src)">
  <span class="product-image-container product-image-container-1198" style="width: 388px;">
        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 125%;">
            <img class="product-image-photo" src="http://example.com/media/catalog/product/l/i/example_d17163a-a00_t-shirt_bra_white-min.jpg?width=388&amp;height=485&amp;store=example_en&amp;image-type=small_image">
        </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Don't use inline `on*` and `style` attributes. Rather:

```js
const ELS_prodLink = document.querySelectorAll(".product-link");

ELS_prodLink.forEach((EL_pr) => {
  EL_pr.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    
    const EL_img = EL_pr.querySelector(".product-image-photo");
    console.log(EL_img.src);
    
  });
});
```

```css
.product-image-container { width: 388px; }
.product-image-wrapper { padding-bottom: 125% }
```

```html
<a class="product-link" href="http://example.com/example-2pp.html">
  <span class="product-image-container product-image-container-1198">
     <span class="product-image-wrapper" >
        <img class="product-image-photo" src="http://example.com/media/catalog/product/l/i/example_d17163a-a00_t-shirt_bra_white-min.jpg?width=388&amp;height=485&amp;store=example_en&amp;image-type=small_image">
    </span>
  </span>
</a>
```